# C++/cli interface with properties not usable from c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Cli interface looks like this:

```
using namespace System::Timer
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface class ITimerProvider
    {
        property Timer AppTimer
        {
             Timer get();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting to a c# class deriving from that interface and using "implement interface" from right-click menu in VS2013, it creates:

```
public void get_AppTimer(ref Timer value)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The compiler complains "MyProject does not implement interface member `MyCLIProject.Interfaces.ITimerprovider.get_AppTimer()`"

It does so, even when it has put it inside by itself.

Comment: You have a *lot* of typos in that snippet.  But the most relevant one is surely that you did not declare the property correctly.  Timer is a reference type, you need to return a reference to the object to stay compatible with other managed languages.  Use `property Timer^ AppTimer`, note the added ^ hat.

Comment: Thanks. You have indirectly given the answer. Doing so with the reference type, vs2013 will create the interface implementation code you would expect. And it compiles fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans has given the answer. Correcting interface declaration leads to expected auto-generated code and the project compiles fine:

```
property Timer^ AppTimer
    {
         Timer^ get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be due to Visual Studio not generating the code correctly for you.

While technically properties are just syntactic sugar for the methods `get_propertyName()` and `set_PropertyName()`, you don't actually write those methods in C# when implementing a property. The correct C# code for implementing the property would be this:

```
class MyProject
{
    public Timer AppTimer
    {
        get
        {
            // return the value here
        }
    }
}
```

If you change your code to something like this, that should fix the error.

Comment: Correct. I wondered why the vs2013 puts in the strange get_..() method. It's due to the missing reference type in the interface declaration. It compiles fine and so I did not see the error first. Doing it with reference types, the auto-generated code looks like the one you posted.